# Erro em listagem de clientes que não realizaram compras Opencart

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, opencart

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver de maneira alguma. Estou tentando listar apenas os clientes que nunca efetuaram compras, ou seja, verificando na tabela order se não existe nenhuma compra associada ao id do cliente, estou usando a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` AS c INNER JOIN `" .
DB_PREFIX . "order` AS o ON (c.customer_id = o.customer_id) INNER JOIN
`" . DB_PREFIX . "address` AS a ON (c.address_id = a.address_id) WHERE
o.customer_id is null"
```

Assim está meu model:
https://pastebin.com/ecA0HY4z

O controller:
https://pastebin.com/YwEpULC3

E a view:
https://pastebin.com/FGS4Dcj4

Quando removo o where para testar apenas a listagem, aparecem esses erros:
https://pastebin.com/yWJ8zhTC

Mas não retorna os valores, acredito que eu tenha usado o where de maneira errada nessa consulta. Como posso resolver?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Checar se existe alguma compra associada ao usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240830/checar-se-existe-alguma-compra-associada-ao-usu%c3%a1rio)

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta 2 vezes, aguarde alguém responder, coloque o código no corpo da pergunta, recomendo que leia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [Como formatar minhas publicações usando o Markdown ou HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e [O que devo fazer se ninguém responder à minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)